# Source for conjectures in commutative algebra

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, open-problems

Do you know some *books/survey papers/ websites* on conjectures or open problems in commutative ring theory? I want to see if
there are very famous open problems or conjectures in commutative ring theory.

Thank you.

Comment: Ones like "*Open problems in commutative ring theory*" by
Paul-Jean Cahen, Marco Fontana, Sophie Frisch and Sarah Glaz

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_conjectures_in_commutative_algebra

Comment: A lot of the ones on the wikipedia page are solved, ie Yves André also proved the existence of weakly functorial big Cohen-Macaulay algebras which implies many of the others on the list.